# ZFS backward compatibility

Tags: zfs

I have two systems, on with ZFS on Linux version 0.8.2 and another with version 0.8.3. Can I safely move ZFS media from one to the other and back?
Thanks,
Phil

Comment: What OS/releases are you talking about?  or what package does that version number relate to?  as it's not a Linux (kernel) version  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=zfs)

Comment: I plan to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-88 64-bit and RedHat 77 which  has kernel 4.14.0-115. I'm doing this because I have software which depends on RedHat7. The ZFS on Linux install for RedHat7.7 is version 0.8.3 whereas my Ubuntu has ZFS version 0.8.2. The question is:

Comment: I suspect the question may have been better suited to SE's Unix & Linux rather than Ask Ubuntu.  RHEL/CentOS software is very old compared to Ubuntu so you want admins who've used both rather than just Ubuntu releases.

Comment: I plan to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-88 64-bit and RedHat 77 which  has kernel 4.14.0-115. I'm doing this because I have software which depends on RedHat7. The ZFS on Linux install for RedHat7.7 is version 0.8.3 whereas my Ubuntu has ZFS version 0.8.2. The question is: Can I mount the ZFS filesystems alternately with each OS without causing harm due to potential incompatibilities between ZFS 0.8.2 and ZFS 0.8.3? Thanks

Comment: Please place those details in your question so more people see them (you can edit your own question).  You want as many people as possible to read it so you're chance of getting useful help is increased (*most skip comments*)

Answer (score 1):

ZFS should be backwards compatible, as long as you don't upgrade the on-disk zpool and zfs versions beyond what the oldest/ lowest version  ZFS system supports.

Also ZFS should be compatible between distributions, but I have no experience dong it.